# How to upload from clipboard in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, sap-gui

After executing a transaction, I get bunch of user ids, then I copy it and paste it into another part of the transaction.

In the below code, I copy user ids in the first part and store it in BNAME.

VBA is unable to upload from the clipboard in the second part.

Maybe it is not liking Ctrl+C in the first part.

```vb
Set SAPGUIAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

Set SAPapplication = SAPGUIAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SAPapplication.Children(0)

Set session = Connection.Children(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "suim"

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

**######first part######**

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "02  1      2"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01  1      1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "03  2      7"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectItem "04  2      8", "1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "04  2      8", "1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01  1      1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickLink "04  2      8", "1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_ACTGRPS_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = "*******"

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").Text = "***********"

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,2]").Text = "************"

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,2]").SetFocus

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,2]").caretPosition = 18

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").currentCellRow = -1


session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectColumn "BNAME"

**#####Got Bunch of User Ids and copied it with the help of Ctrl+C ######**

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press

**###### second part######**
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "02  1     10"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01  1      1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectItem "03  3      1", "1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "03  3      1", "1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickLink "03  3      1", "1"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_USER_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
'...    
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectColumn "BNAME"
'---------------------- new -----------------------------------------
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectContextMenuItemByPosition "0"
'---------------------- new -----------------------------------------
'#####Got Bunch of User Ids and copied it with the help of Ctrl+C ######
'...
```